# What is a suitable replacement for android ActionBar?

Tags: java, android

I've developed an application that utilizes an actionBar, but apparently actionBar is only available for SDK 3.0 or later. I would like my application to be able to run on earlier SDKs, what would be a suitable replacement for an actionBar?

- Pop up menu
- Context Menu etc..

Please suggest anything that you think would be a suitable replacement or similar to an actionbar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

no, you can also use Actionbar Sherlock which supports below Verion 3.0 and it good too. It is a library project and you just need to add reference to your project.

http://actionbarsherlock.com/

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock

[image]

Comment: Is this stable and functional on all android supported platforms?

Comment: yes, it is. I also worked with it. you need to set Theme to your activity in your manifest file. Lots of example avail on Web too

Comment: [GreenDroid](http://greendroid.cyrilmottier.com/) is another good ui library which contains _action-bar_ component.

Comment: @hotveryspicy Getting error in library> values, values-v11, values-v14, can tell me what wrong I am doing?

Comment: make you project Api level above 3, and minSdk="7".

Comment: @hotveryspicy But by default it is selected 2.1 then it should work na, and I am getting error in library.

Comment: no, increase Api level to 3 or 4., it will work in below version too dnt worry.

Comment: Yet facing error, `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;` I changed APi level to 4.

Comment: have you updated your ADT to 17, then please suffix lib like libs then try.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the native google ActionBarCompat from support library:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html

Comment: Hey, did you read his question as well as your answered, He want below 3.0 and you given for 3.0 and above.

Comment: @RobinHood 
The ActionBarCompat was designed for API < 11, hence the Compat as in Compatibility in the name ActionBarCompat.

Answer (score 0):

Some bugs still exist but it depends on how you use the library. The
library is certainly more stable